# Trying to compress my ui-router state definitions by putting the state object into a variable. Doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So here is my code. I'm sure there is something simple that I have wrong, but I'm just not figuring out why this isn't working. It works if I replace each logState with the contents of the variable, but I can't get the variable to work. It doesn't error at all.

```
.config(function config( $stateProvider) {
    var logState = {
        url: '/log',
        controller: 'logController',
        templateUrl: 'log/log.tpl.html',
        resolve: {
            vData: ['$http', 'apiUrl', function($http, apiUrl)
            {
                return $http.get(apiUrl+ '/emaillog');
            }]
            },
            data:{ pageTitle: "Log"}
        };
    $stateProvider
    .state( 'log', logState)
    .state( 'parents.parent.log', logState)
    .state( 'parents.parents.children.child.log', logState)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, maybe you can try to make a copy of variable and pass that into the function?

```
$stateProvider
.state( 'log', angular.copy(logState))
.state( 'parents.parent.log', angular.copy(logState))
.state( 'parents.parents.children.child.log', angular.copy(logState));
```

Comment: Ding Ding Ding!  We have a winner! I never would have come up with this on my own. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Parents must exist: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#parent-must-exist. Maybe this is the issue with 'parents.parent.log' and 'parents.parents.children.child.log'
- When nesting views, your template (here log.html) needs to contain an ui-view

Comment: I'm already aware of those requirements, and abstracted them away for clarity sake.